# Alternative of onclick for html5

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, firefox-os

```
 <div id="btnSideToggle" onclick="Viewer.toggleThumbnails();"><img src="assets/pgThumbs.png"></div>
```

Due to CSP restriction on Firefox OS Marketplace i cant use onclick on html5 page, can anyone please tell me alternative of onclick for HTML5

here is the full code :
http://jsfiddle.net/edd4225/v65qZ/

Comment: `.addEventListner` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: addEventListner Only works on Javascript not on HTML page, i tried that too but still no success

Answer (score 4):

This will work for you

```
var button = document.querySelector("#btnSideToggle");

button.addEventListener("click", function onclick(event) {
  Viewer.toggleThumbnails();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

---

You could simplify it with `Function.prototype.bind` (requires ECMAScript `>= 5`)

```
button.addEventListener("click", Viewer.toggleThumbnails.bind(Viewer));
```

**Note** that an `Event` will still be sent as the first argument to the `toggleThumbnails` handler.

Comment: But this wont work in HTML5 page,                               <div id="btnSideToggle" ><script type:"text/javascript">var button = document.querySelector("#btnSideToggle");

button.addEventListener("click", function onclick(event) {
  Viewer.toggleThumbnails();
  event.preventDefault();
});</script><img src="assets/pgThumbs.png"></div>

Comment: Can you be more clear on "won't work"? How about you setup a http://jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: here is the code, can you please help me in replacing onclick and onchange with something that follows Content  Security Policy Of Firefox OS App Market   http://jsfiddle.net/edd4225/v65qZ/

Comment: Add the external js file and then use querySelector to add the onclick like: http://jsfiddle.net/LPr7Z/  The Firefox OS restriction is against inline scripts not onClick. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/CSP

Comment: @JasonWeathersby here is one quote from FAQs of above page given by you...."Why don't my click or hover events fire?
    If you're setting click or mouse event handlers with onclick="" or onmouseover="", your code violates the CSP. You cannot set event attributes in a privileged packaged app. You should use addEventListener() instead."

Comment: @JasonWeathersby can you please tell me how to link <button id="mybutton" > to external js script, because CSP do not allow inline script , how come i link it with external js

Comment: @JasonWeathersby http://jsfiddle.net/v4H3t/1/ here the code is working but when i implement it on html page , i had no clue what went wrong, its not working

Comment: @user3731917 put the js code in a separate file and link it to your HTML header like <script type="text/javascript" src="yourjsfile.js"></script>